# Eventbus and Controldata

Tags: java, guava, event-bus

In my application I have an eventbus distributing messages coming from outside. I want to distribute that messages including some Controldata. The kind of object I would like to use is something like this

```
class NewMessage<MESSAGE_TYPE> {
  MESSAGE_TYPE message;
  Controldata controldata;
}
```

Since I cannot subscribe for the generic

```
NewMessage<MyMessage>
```

I created a workaround

```
class MyMessage extends Controldata {
}
```

So I can subscribe for `MyMessage`. Another solution would be to create a new wrapper class per message.

However I don't like both solutions. The one because MyMessage is NOT a Controldata, the other one implies to much oerhead. Any ideas how to solve this cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

Not many choices. If you want to be able to subscribe to different message types but those types don't include the data then storing the data externally can work:

```
private static Map<Object, ControlData> controlDataMap =
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<>());

public void publish(Object message, ControlData data) {
    controlDataMap.put(message, data);
    bus.post(message);
}

@Subscribe void foo(SomeMessage msg) {
    ControlData data = controlDataMap.get(msg);
    // do things.
}
```

Cleanup of the map is automatic (as long as events are garbage collected once the event is handled) but may not work really well under gc pressure.

The second limitation: event objects need to be unique and have to have a sane equals/hashcode implementation.

Other than that, you may write your own event bus implementation / extend from what guava gives you. It's unfortunately not the most flexible bus.